# Expected value of discrete and continuous random variables.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I wanted to confirm something. If we are given a discrete random variable's CDF and we want to find it's expected value we use summation formula. And for continuous we integrate the CDf to find expected value. Right?

Comment: You mean the pdf?

Comment: this is what  is confusing me. in continuous do we use pdf or cdf?

Comment: In general $\int xdF(x)$ in both cases. If the rv is discrete then this integral can be written as a summation.

Comment: The pdf in both cases

Comment: I'd like to direct you to this site: https://newonlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/126/